# How to resolve "Could not find the provider 'certStoreSettings'"

Tags: certificate, webdeploy, iis-8.5

I have two IIS Servers.

I use the Web Deploy Tool to create a package so I can duplicate the sites on Server 1, on Server 2.

I try to import the site package on Server 2 and it starts the import and then gives this message:

`Could not find the provider 'certStoreSettings' Please verify that you've entered the provider name correctly.`

I am guessing that it has something to do with a security certificate that one of the sites uses.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have the same version of WebDeploy installed on both servers.  3.6 is the latest version.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717